How to add a key/name for response in drf spectacular
i have a resonse in extend_schema() :
patch = extend_schema(
    description='city',
    parameters=[
        OpenApiParameter("Accept-Language", OpenApiTypes.NUMBER, OpenApiParameter.HEADER),
        ],
    request={
        "application/json": inline_serializer(
            name="InlineOneCityPatchSerializer",
            fields={
                "country_id": serializers.IntegerField(),
            },
        ),
    },
    #responses = CityStateSerializer
    responses={
        200: OpenApiResponse(response=CityStateSerializer(many=True),
                             description='city response' ,),
        400: OpenApiResponse(description='Bad request (something invalid)'),
    },
),

response is like below:
[
  {
    "id": 0,
     ...
  }
]

i want to add a key/name "results" for response like :
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 0,
       ...
    }
    {
      "id": 0,
       ...
    }
    {
      "id": 1,
       ...
    }
    {
      "id": 2,
       ...
    }
  ]
}


One approach could be to define a different serializer that includes the results key. That would look something like this:
from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema_field
from rest_framework import serializers


class CityStateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...


class CityStateWithResultsSerializer(serializers.Serializer)
    results = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        "get_results"
    )

    @extend_schema_field(CityStateSerializer(many=True))
    def get_results(self, obj):
        qs = YourModel.objects.all()

        return CityStateSerializer(qs, many=True).data

Your response would then be:
...
responses={
    200: OpenApiResponse(response=CityStateWithResultsSerializer,
                            description='city response' ,),
},
...

This would allow you to have an accurate schema, regardless of any future changes you may make to the CityStateSerializer class.
